Docker daemon DNS fails
Summary of question: When trying to docker pull from any repository other than the default, e.g. docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 the command fails with dial tcp: lookup mcr.microsoft.com on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host, here is the full text of the two kinds of failures I get:
Error response from daemon: Get "https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/dotnet/sdk/manifests/sha256:03476e8b9
74ca8e5084bf63742d85f04a5f53df0ae37c82d31bae228eb297e6c": dial tcp: lookup mcr.microsoft.com on 8.8
.8.8:53: no such host

Error response from daemon: Head "https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/dotnet/sdk/manifests/8.0": dial tcp:
 lookup mcr.microsoft.com on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host

Note This does work on an identical system at another site.
Details
This happens on an Alpine Linux system with the uname -a output of:
Linux server3 6.1.90-0-lts #1-Alpine SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon, 06 May 2024 08:14:42 +0000 x86_64 Linux
The content of /etc/resolv.conf is:
search Home
nameserver 8.8.8.8

dig works properly, here is the output of dig mcr.microsoft.com:
; <<>> DiG 9.18.24 <<>> mcr.microsoft.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29364
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mcr.microsoft.com.             IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mcr.microsoft.com.      2018    IN      CNAME   global.fe.mscr.io.
global.fe.mscr.io.      120     IN      CNAME   mcr-microsoft-com.a-0016.a-msedge.net.
mcr-microsoft-com.a-0016.a-msedge.net. 240 IN CNAME a-0016.a-msedge.net.
a-0016.a-msedge.net.    60      IN      A       204.79.197.219

;; Query time: 13 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue May 07 12:43:55 IDT 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 158

This is the output of docker version:
Client:
 Version:           25.0.5
 API version:       1.44
 Go version:        go1.20.11
 Git commit:        d260a54c81efcc3f00fe67dee78c94b16c2f8692
 Built:             Mon Apr 15 18:14:16 2024
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          25.0.5
  API version:      1.44 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.20.11
  Git commit:       e63daec8672d77ac0b2b5c262ef525c7cf17fd20
  Built:            Mon Apr 15 18:14:16 2024
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.7.2
  GitCommit:        0cae528dd6cb557f7201036e9f43420650207b58
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.12
  GitCommit:        51d5e94601ceffbbd85688df1c928ecccbfa4685
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:

Curious Anomaly
Sometimes, dig responds as such (and only on the problematic system, never on the other one):
;; Warning: Message parser reports malformed message packet.

; <<>> DiG 9.18.24 <<>> mcr.microsoft.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48685
;; flags: qr; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mcr.microsoft.com.             IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
.                       0       CLASS1232 OPT   10 8 Je7iYkWs5OA=

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
mcr.microsoft.com.      207     IN      A       204.79.197.219

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue May 07 12:37:11 IDT 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 74

The base 64 string (Je7iYkWs5OA= above) is always different in each such result.
